# Connection between jmonkey and netbeans

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, jmonkeyengine

I'm working on a project for school. We are are making a harbour where you can load and unload ships. The control part is made in `Netbeans` and the simulation in `JME`. 
We send data from Netbeans to `JME` via a socket. JME is running a serversocket who is liseting to the input from `Netbeans`.

For example `Netbeans` sends an ID of a container and the crane in `JME` gets that container and puts it on the shore so a verhicle can pick it up.

We change a count in the main (`Main.count = 2`) so the `SimpleUpdate` can call a method. The problem is that sometimes stuff is getting skipped. Also I think it's getting worse when we send more information for instance a vehicle that's getting the container. How can I fix this? And are there other ways to get a good connection?

The code:

**Netbeans**

*Send client*

```
public static void run() throws Exception
{     
    Socket socket = new Socket("Localhost", 4321);      
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());     
}

//Sent arraystring to Simulation
public void sent(String sentString){
    try {
        out.writeObject(sentString); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CommunicationWithSimulatoin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

*Main send some stuff example*

```
for(int i = Calculator.getContainersFromMaritime(); i > 1; i--)
{
    Thread.sleep(50);
    sim.sent("craneCon;" + i + ";");
    System.out.println(i);            
}
```

**JME**

*Listener*

```
public static void Listener() throws Exception {
    boolean isRunning = true;
    //Creates the server socket
    ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);
    //Acception a connection from the client

    Socket socket = sSocket.accept();
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    //Get the input from the client

    while (isRunning) {
        //Reads and prints the input
        test = (String) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(test);
        String[] parts = receivedString.split(";");

        if(parts[0].equals("ContainerPositionsMaritime"))
        {
            Maritime.ContainersOnBoard = receivedString.split(";");
            Main.count = 0;
        }
        if(parts[0].equals("craneCon"))
        {
            int containerId = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            SeagoingCranes.idContainer = containerId;
            Main.count = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

*Main simpleupdate*

```
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
    if(count == 0)
    {
        InitContainers();
        //martime.setLocalTranslation(0, 500.0f, 0);
        count = 999;
    }
    if(count == 2)
    {
        InitCrane(SeagoingCranes.idContainer);
        count = 999;
    }
    if(martime != null)
    {
        martime.move(0,0,0.25f*tpf);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the control being in netbeans? Do you mean you are running a simple application in netbeans?

Comment: With the control I mean it is sending what the JME parts must do like get that container or send that vehicle to that place and pick up that container.

Comment: I can't answer this question but be aware that netbeans is just an IDE, it is not a part of your program; it's what you write your program with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your program.

Firstly - you have potential race and thread contention issues as you have "count" which I assume is an integer value inside the `SimpleApplication` is being modified from one thread and read from another. Unless the value is declared as volatile this can cause all sorts of unexpected problems and odd behaviour and even declaring it as volatile is not recommended.

Your main issue though (even leaving aside the subtle problems) is being caused by the fact that in `simpleUpdate()` you are scanning count and then taking an action based on count. `simpleUpdate()` is called once for each frame as your jME3 application is running.

If you receive more than one message in a frame then only the last one will be acted on as the count will be modified again before the next `simpleUpdate()` runs.

The best way to do this is to use `app.enqueue()`.

```
        if(parts[0].equals("ContainerPositionsMaritime"))
        {
            final ContainersOnBoard containers = receivedString.split(";");
            mainApp.enqueue(new Callable<Spatial>() {
                public Spatial call() throws Exception {
                    mainApp.InitContainers(containers);
                    return null;
                }
            });                   
            }

        }
```

You can remove all the existing code from your `simpleUpdate()`.

The `Callable` you `enqueue` will be called back from the JME3 thread in the next update and process the addition of the containers. By doing a similar thing for every different commands it will `enqueue` and process all the commands as the time comes. You can `enqueue` as many commands as you like and they will all be processed.

In general you should read up on AppStates, Controls and the threading model as they will allow you to make your code much more structured and organised.

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:multithreading

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:application_states

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:custom_controls

P.S. You should try and follow Java style/coding conventions - for example methods should begin with lowercase. initContainers not InitContainers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will work on this :). I usually use the lowercase but I'm working in a group and not everyone is using that too.